# What may be wrong with my central locking?

Tags: electrical, skoda

My Skoda Felicia from 1998 has central locking (not remotely) which has problems. The doors can be unlocked through central locking from the front doors. However, the driver's side door only unlocks the  rear right door and the passenger's side door unlocks all but the rear left door.

So, schematically:

```
                            Left Front   Right Front   Left rear   Right rear
Left front (un)locks  :         x                                      x
Right front (un)locks :         x             x                        x
```

What may be wrong with my central locking system?

Comment: You have a problem with the right front and left rear door. I'm not sure if this system is operated by electric motors or by air? You have to check the cables/air hoses on  right front and left rear doors.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a dodgy connection on one or more wires. The wires to and from each lock have to go through the 'snake' connecting the door to the bodyshell, and this typically is the most likely place for failures to occur, particularly on the driver's door (the one opened and shut most frequently, twisting the wires more and thus fatigueing them more).

Depending on the design, you will probably have a multi-plug at one or both ends of the snake - you should be able to use a multimeter here to figure out if any of the wires have broken. Hopefully you'll then be able to replace the offending wire, or repair it.

Comment: This might explain the left rear not working at all... However, how is it possible that the front right door unlocks the rear right, but the front left doesn't?

Comment: It could be that the signal wire going to the right front is broken - i.e. both front doors tell the system to open, but only the left front and right rear actually work. The right front is only unlocked by the mechanical linkage from its own keyhole.